# How to add shadows that go below other views

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a header view, a header shadow view and a table view. The header view has a clear background. The header shadow view has a light blue background color and only have 1px height. The table view is not clipped to bounds.

So the effect here is when you scroll up, the table view contents will pass through the transparent header view.

**The problem here is that the view with the shadow goes above the table view contents so when you scroll up, there's a thin line of blue with a shadow. If you will check the star on macy's you will see the thin blue line overlapping with the contents.**
[image: Overlapping view]

Comment: if you add shadow view programmatically why don't you add below the tableview with  insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)

Comment: I add only the shadow programatically. The view is in the storyboard. The problem here is, the shadow can only be applied on a view with a solid color background. The shadow doesn't appear on a clear color background

Comment: That's why I told you to use UIView rather.

Comment: Hmmm let me try that adding of view programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

if it is tableView cell add a view as a background view for applying shadow and set shadow for that view

try this code:

```
func setShadow(view:UIView){
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5 // set cornerRadius you want
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0 // set shadow Radius you want
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5 // set shadow opacity you want
}
```

to set shadow

```
setShadow(view:yourView)
```

Comment: No problem with shadows here. Check the edit. I made some clarifications with the image

Comment: Yes it's a custom

Comment: @BryanPosas so when you are setting constraint of tableView, set the top constraint of tableView to the bottom of your custom navigationbar

Answer (score 0):

1.First You can take UIView in tableview Cell

2.Then Create One CardsView class Below I mentioned

3.after you give to UIView  class name is Cardsview

// Please Paste in your Project...

import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class CardsView: UIView {

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10   //replece 2
@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.black
@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

override func layoutSubviews() {

    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
    layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
 layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
```

}

Comment: No problem with shadows here. Check the edit. I made some clarifications with the image

Comment: Sorry @BryanPosas I will check it